# mvn test doesn't run any test (JUnit 4 or JUnit 5)

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea

I know what you'll think in the first place: "You should name your test classes with 'Test' in it etc." 
 But the problem is: it's already the case. I did scroll every possible SO post and didn't find anything, so no, unfortunately, this is not a duplicate.

I even have a test class named TestPleaseWillYouRunMyTest and a test method called testPleaseTest().

When I run a "mvn test", the "target/test-classes" folder is well populated, so I really don't understand why my tests aren't run...

Just in case it would help understand the problem, here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumTests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <testSourceDirectory> src/test/java </testSourceDirectory>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Which testing framework would you like to use: JUnit Jupiter or TestNG? BTW: Remove `<testSourceDirectory> src/test/java </testSourceDirectory>` let Maven handle that.

Comment: Setting source and target to 10 is not the best idea. Use an LTS version like Java 8 or Java 11.

Comment: Could you please share your test class sample

Comment: Why you added testng, junit 4 and 5? first decide which testing framework you want to use

Comment: @Nomanaliabbasi you helped me solve my problem: I had to delete the testng dependency from my POM. Please write it as an answer of this post so I can offer you all the rep you deserve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you added testng, junit 4 and 5? first decide which testing framework you want to use

Comment: You helped me solve my problem: I had to delete the testng dependency from my POM ;)

Answer (score -1):

just to add my 5 cent to what khmarbaise said:
if your tests sit in standard directory you don't need to add testSourceDirectory at all, this tag is for non standard places.
Also you entry there is incorrect: src/test/java - this is definitely not the place where your test are.

Comment: How can you possibly know where my tests are? :D

Comment: your path is the standard one however still incorrect, it should start with project location anyway

Answer (score -1):

```
mvn test
```

Only compiles the test classes but does not run the tests. In order to let the tests run use:

```
mvn verify
```

Comment: This is not correct: in another project on another machine with the same POM and the same project structure, I'm able to run all tests with `mvn test`.